# Copy files matching a name in different folders

Tags: linux, find

I am using

```
find ../../ -type f -name <filename>*.PDF -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=Directory name with path>;
```

but it is copy only one file. It doesn't copy all files which is having same name. I need number of files to be searched and copied which is having same name but it it created on different date and different folder. how to solve this issue. I have already created lot's more I am facing the problem in this regard.

Comment: how can you copy files with the same name to the same folder? they will overwrite each other.

Comment: to allow a duplicate basename, you could create a tar archive instead of saving the files to the same directory: `find ../../ -iname \*.pdf -type f -print0 | tar --null -T - -cf /path/to/pdfs.tar` OR to append unique suffixes to duplicate filenames in the input: `find ... -print0 | perl -MFile::Basename -0lpe's/$/"." . $f{basename $_}/e if $f{basename $_}++' | xargs -0 ...`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the duplicate files. Once you have the name, you can `find` them and delete them using your script:

```
for i in `find .|grep pom.xml`; do 
   basename $i;
done |sort|uniq -c|sort -n|cut -b9-
```

PS: everyone's in a hurry. Adding urgency to your posts is usually frowned upon in StackOverflow, and you might prompt the opposite reaction

Comment: I don't want to delete. I want to copied it.find ../../ -type f -name <filename>*.PDF -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=Directory name with path>;